# Strapi problem - file ./config/plugins.js missing in strappi

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, strapi

I can't find the "plugins.js" file inside the "config" folder in my strapi project.

[Strapi Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iXVv.png)

I want to set my jwt to expire in 7 days instead of 30 which is its default value, but in order to do that, according to the documentation it tells me that I have to change the value from the path "./config/plugins.js"

[strapi documentation - https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/plugins/users-permissions.html#jwt-configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qP74E.png)

What should I do?
Where can I set the expiration of my jwt?